# Cloud Function does not save to Firestore when deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a cloud function that loads an API and saves its contents to my Firestore database. It is working perfectly when I run the cloud function on my local environment using the firebase emulators. However, when I have deployed the same function to the Google Cloud Platform, it fails to save the contents to Firestore although it loads the API successfully. What else could I have been missing from my setup?

Here is the code. I purposely redacted the API link.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const axios = require('axios');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

 exports.savePSEData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const url = <LINK REDACTED>;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(response => {
                const date = response.data.as_of;
                for (var index in response.data.stock) {
                    var stock = response.data.stock[index]
                    createStockDocument(date, stock.symbol, stock.price.amount, stock.percent_change, stock.volume, callback => {
                        console.log(index)
                    })
                }
               return res.status(200).send("ok");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
               return res.status(500).send(error);
            });
    })

});

function createStockDocument(date, symbol, amount, percentChange, volume, callback) {
    console.log("Creating temp package")
    const docRef = admin.firestore().doc(`${symbol}/${date}`);
    docRef.set({ 
        amount: amount,
        percent_change: percentChange,
        volume: volume
    })
    .then(docRef => {
        console.log('Document created')
        return callback(docRef)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(`Error trying to create document ${error}`)
        return callback(error);
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ignoring the promise returned by `docRef.set().then(...).catch(...)`.  Calling `then` and `catch` does not fully handle the promise.  `catch` just returns another promise that resolves asynchronously after the entire chain resolves.  This means that your function is also sending the response to the client **before** Firestore has completed the write, which means it might never complete.  [Functions are terminated immediately after the response is set.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

You should make `createStockDocument` return that promise from the chain, then make the caller of the function wait for it before sending the response.  Minimally:

```
function createStockDocument(date, symbol, amount, percentChange, volume, callback) {
    console.log("Creating temp package")
    const docRef = admin.firestore().doc(`${symbol}/${date}`);
    return docRef.set(...).then(...)
}
```

I suggest not using catch here, and instead have the caller catcher any errors.

```
createStockDocument(...)
.then(() => res.status(200).send("ok"))
.catch(error => res.status(500).send(error))
```

I strongly suggest getting a firm grasp of how promises work, as they are crucial to writing effective code in Cloud Functions.